# Print out the input into an array by calling the function but its not working

Tags: c++, arrays, string

i know this is a simple problem solving but i'm still cannot figure it out. i'm trying to print out the input into an array by calling the function but its not working. Help me. below down here is the code. main.cpp and groovy.h. for your information, i am new to programming

**Here is the output that i get**

[image]

//main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "groovy.h"
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void displayInventory(const groovy[], int);

int main() {
  int s;

  const int size = 20;
  groovy car[size];
  /*= { 
    groovy("M01", "Mazda CX5", 132403.00),
    groovy("M02", "Mazda CX3", 126829.00),
    groovy("M03", "Mazda 6 Grand Touring", 208408.00),
    groovy("M04", "Mazda CX8", 173038.00),
  };

  cout<<"\nList of available car : \n"<<endl;
  displayInventory(car, size);
*/
  string code, model;
  double price;

  cout<<"\nPlease enter model details :- "<<endl;
  cout<<"Model code : ";
  cin>>code;
  cout<<"Model name : ";
  cin>>model;
  cout<<"Model price : ";
  cin>>price;
  
  car[size].storeInfo(code, model, price);
  displayInventory(car, size);

  return 0;
}

void displayInventory(const groovy object[], int size){
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    cout<<setw(5)<<left<<object[i].getCode()
        <<setw(28)<<left<<object[i].getModel()
        <<"RM "<<right<<object[i].getPrice()<<endl;
  }
}
```

//groovy.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class groovy{
  private:
    string modelCode;
    string model;
    double price;
  
  public:
    groovy(){
      modelCode = "XXX";
      model = " ";
      price = 0.0;
    }
    groovy(string c,string m, double p){
      modelCode = c;
      model = m;
      price = p;
    }
    void storeInfo(string c,string m, double p) {
      modelCode = c;
      model = m;
      price = p;
    }
    string getCode() const {
      string code = modelCode;
      return code;
    }
    string getModel() const {
      string m = model;
      return m;
    }
    double getPrice() const {
      double p = price;
      return price;
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: You may want to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 0):

```
  car[size].storeInfo(code, model, price);
```

is bad because the array `car` has only `size` elements: `car[0]` to `car[size-1]`.

The index must be not less than 0 and less than `size`.

Try

```
  car[0].storeInfo(code, model, price);
```

instead.